# Getting directory exists even deleted from gallery

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-storage

I'm surprised when delete folder from gallery and getting that folder by programatically it's returning isExists() = true.

```
if(File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), directory).exists()) {
   return true
}
```

**Note: However it's happening mostly customised devices of android, is there any way to find directory is exists or not?**

Comment: this is standard Directory. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#DIRECTORY_PICTURES. if you delete  I think it will be recreate by OS again.

Comment: I'm deleting directory whatever my application has generated not PICTURE directory, you can check directory field in File(..., directory). @KuLdipPaTel

Answer (score 1):

When you call `File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), directory)` you are actually creating folder and then you are checking for exist of that file, so you were always get true. Lookout documentation for constructor of `File(File parent, String child)`.

**Creates a new  instance from a parent abstract**

better to use concet string and get file like `File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath()+ directory)` to check exist or not.